# How to make docker container built with php:7.2.21-fpm install debian packages from local debian mirror?

Tags: php, docker, debian

I have a docker container built off `php:7.2.21-fpm` from https://hub.docker.com/_/php

- .dockerfile contains `FROM php:7.2.21-fpm as base`

During installation required packages are being downloaded from cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian

- .dockerfile contains `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ...`

And the download speed is around 200kbytes/sec.

Is this possible to make the image fetch debian packages from a local mirror? 
https://www.debian.org/mirror/list

So that download speed would be up to 10Mbytes/sec during installation.

Clarification: I'm in Belarus and my local system downloads updates from BY mirrors.

Comment: [This post](https://developpaper.com/replacing-debian-system-mirror-source-in-docker-or-laradock-to-solve-software-installation-problems/) might help you with that, or at least point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php:7.2.21-fpm uses debian:buster-slim as according to [here](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/2533f47df2522d4157ae034438d085d226a73ea1/7.4-rc/buster/fpm/Dockerfile)

So, to almost every debian distro you can change the mirrors by overriding sources.list, leading us to [Belarus Mirror](https://linuxconfig.org/debian-apt-get-buster-sources-list):

```sh
# Update apt-get source
RUN echo \
    deb http://ftp.by.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://ftp.by.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
    > /etc/apt/sources.list
```